# Javascript slideshow controls don't take any action

Tags: javascript, pagination, slideshow

I've made a slideshow in native javascript but the next and previous buttons don't work. Also the pagination dots should follow the respective slide.

When pressing the next button, the next slide should display and so on. In devTools it shows the first slide has the style set to display and the first dot has the active class added but when pressing the next/prev buttons nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("nextSlide").addEventListener("click",nextSlide());
document.getElementById("prevSlide").addEventListener("click",prevSlide());     

};

var slideIndex = 0;

function nextSlide() {   
var slideList = document.getElementsByClassName("imgSlide");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
slideIndex += 1;

if (slideIndex >= slideList.length) { 
   slideIndex = 0;
} 

for(var i = 0; i < slideList.length; i++) {
   slideList[i].style.display = "none";        
}    

for(var d = 0; d < dots.length; d++) {
   dots[d].classList.remove("active");
}

   slideList[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
   dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
   return false;    
 }   

function prevSlide() {   
var slideList = document.getElementsByClassName("imgSlide");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
slideIndex -= 1;

if (slideIndex < 0) (slideList.length - 1); 

for(var i = 0; i < slideList.length; i++) {
   slideList[i].style.display = "none";                       
   } 

for(var d = 0; d < dots.length; d++) {
   dots[d].classList.remove("active");
 }   

   slideList[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
   dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active"); 
}
```

And my HTML

```
<div id="slides-container">
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="imgSlide"><img 
    src="/BackOffice/viagens_header_images/blobid1508696899148.jpg" 
    alt="Alpine 
    Scenery" /></li>
    <li class="imgSlide"><img 
    src="/BackOffice/viagens_header_images/blobid1509065118446.jpg" 
    alt="Kalte 
    Rinne" /></li>
    <li class="imgSlide"><img 
    src="/BackOffice/viagens_header_images/blobid1508696913346.jpg" 
    alt="Adiltzgraben" /></li>
    </ul>
<div class="controls"><button type="button" id="prevSlide" role="button">
</button>
<ul class="dot-navigation">
    <li class="dots"></li>
    <li class="dots"></li>
    <li class="dots"></li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="nextSlide" role="button"></button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Listener` parameter in `addEventListener` for a named function must be a function name without quotes and brackets:

```
document.getElementById("nextSlide").addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
document.getElementById("prevSlide").addEventListener("click", prevSlide);
```

And also another small bug. Instead of the line `if (slideIndex < 0) (slideList.length - 1);`
must be:

```
if (slideIndex < 0) {
   slideIndex = slideList.length; 
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("nextSlide").addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
  document.getElementById("prevSlide").addEventListener("click", prevSlide);

};

var slideIndex = 0;

function nextSlide() {
  var slideList = document.getElementsByClassName("imgSlide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
  slideIndex += 1;

  if (slideIndex >= slideList.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < slideList.length; i++) {
    slideList[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (var d = 0; d < dots.length; d++) {
    dots[d].classList.remove("active");
  }

  slideList[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
  return false;
}

function prevSlide() {
  var slideList = document.getElementsByClassName("imgSlide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
  slideIndex -= 1;

  if (slideIndex < 0) {
    slideIndex = slideList.length - 1;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < slideList.length; i++) {
    slideList[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (var d = 0; d < dots.length; d++) {
    dots[d].classList.remove("active");
  }

  slideList[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.imgSlide:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.slides {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="slides-container">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="imgSlide"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="350x150"></li>
    <li class="imgSlide"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="300x200"></li>
    <li class="imgSlide"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="400x300"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="controls">
    <button type="button" id="prevSlide" role="button">Back</button>
    <ul class="dot-navigation">
      <li class="dots"></li>
      <li class="dots"></li>
      <li class="dots"></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" id="nextSlide" role="button">Next</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just finished "polishing" my slideshow with some smooth opacity transition. Looks very nice. Thank you for your help, i´ve checked your answer as the correct one. Cheers